# О канцелярщине

Tags: общие-вопросы, канцеляризмы

Прочитала ответы на свой вопрос о "сроке действия". Во-первых, спасибо всем, кто ответил.
Но вот подумалось: а почему, собственно, канцелярский язык так отличается от русского литературного? Почему тексты документов формулируются каким-то странным, совершенно не разговорным, образом? Может, это пошло от малограмотных чиновников, а потом закрепилось?

Answer (score 2):

У каждого стиля речи свои задачи. Задачи канцеряского стиля, в общем, сводятся к двум вещам:
1. Создание текста без каких-либо двусмысленностей;
2. Упрощение чтения документооборота.

На первую задачу направлено стремление к безличным формам и существительным вместо глаголов, у которых в русском языке чаще всего больше одного значения.

На вторую - знаменитые канцелярские клише, благодаря которым, можно лишь пробежав глазами по документу вычленить из него все важные детали, не вчитываясь в остальной текст ( *Имярек "Прошу... очередной... с даты"* - и все понятно). А это экономит время и силы.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно организованный канцелярский язык направлен на однозначность толкования написанного в юридически значимых документах. Например, в патентах на изобретение при перечислении пронумерованных элементов рисунка пишут "блок 12 усиления" (всегда относя номер к существительному), а не "блок усиления 12", как было бы в более "литературном" тексте (и то, и другое понятно грамотному человеку). Но когда пишут с оборотами типа "согласно правил", то это, действительно, выдаёт малограмотного составителя текстов.

Answer (score 0):

Наоборот, пошло это не от малограмотных, а от грамотных. Письменный язык всегда отличался от устного, а уж язык официальных документов и подавно должен отличаться. Чтоб было видно всем: это именно официальный документ, а не речь малограмотного Вани (а хоть бы и грамотного, но устная все же речь!).

Answer (score 0):

Ох, что-то я сегодня как Баба-Яга – против! Ни с кем не могу согласиться.
«Стремление к безличным формам направлено на создание текста без каких-либо двусмысленностей»? Т.е. «я решил» -это двусмысленность, я «было решено» это недвусмысленно! По-моему безличность порождает коллективную безответственность, для того и была придумана. «Существительные вместо глаголов» уж точно речь не упрощают, как раз наоборот, делают ее более громоздкой. Если у глагола много значений, непросто определить от какого из них образовано существительное – ну нет у нас в языке герундиев.С глаголами это проще –у них богаче система управления.  С Alex_ander согласна: при создании определенного рода документов язык формализуется настолько, что становится похож на язык программирования, но вопрос Fuchoin Kazuki я поняла более широко.
 Реакция Niemand меня удивила. Скажите, [@Niemand](/users/3758/niemand), неужели когда вы слышите речь какого-нибудь чиновника или политика, неумело громоздящего друг не друга отглагольные существительные не в тех падежах и не с теми предлогами, употребляющего слова не в том значении и не с теми ударениями  в попытке выразить какую-нибудь нехитрую мысль (чаще всего тщетной, поскольку трудно разглядеть мысль за таким количеством слов),  вы не смотрите на него как атлет на инвалида? Разве он вам не кажется малограмотным человеком? Да, Ваня грамоте учился, но явно не доучился, словечек поднабрался, а до их смысла не допёр, вот он перед вами, с важным видом роняет умные слова, за которыми пустота, дескать, глядите все, какой я теперь грамотный! И вы ему верите? Кого он может обмануть своей ученостью, кроме совсем уж неграмотных Вань? А задача у канцелярита такая же, как и у всех жаргонов – профессиональных или социальных: идентификация с группой. И мы эту информацию прекрасно считываем.
(Cдается мне, мы все слегка заразились канцеляритом, отвечая на этот вопрос.)

Comment: >> Скажите, @Niemand, неужели когда вы слышите речь какого-нибудь чиновника или политика, неумело громоздящего друг не друга отглагольные существительные не в тех падежах и не с теми предлогами, употребляющего слова не в том значении и не с теми ударениями в попытке выразить какую-нибудь нехитрую мысль (чаще всего тщетной, поскольку трудно разглядеть мысль за таким количеством слов), вы не смотрите на него как атлет на инвалида?

@Тина, дело же не в этом. Нынешний чиновник, бывает, что и малограмотный, но нас спросили об отличии канцелярского языка как такового. Почему он вообще возник и т.д.

Comment: попробую более внятно ответить на заданный вопрос: 
Канцелярит возник в попытке малограмотных, но выбившихся в начальство людей идентифицировать себя с элитой, в том числе интеллектуальной. Не получилось. Удается сойти за своих только в компании таких же амбициозных недоучек, как и они сами. Увы, они не всегда это понимают. Козыряют дипломами и научными степенями, уверенные, что их примут за умных и образованных. Но как раз умные и образованные их за своих и не держат. Не может человек, для которого русский литературный язык родной, не опознать того, для кого он иностранный, как чужака.